# HP Proliant DL120 G6 NIC fault

Tags: debian, hp-proliant

HP Proliant DL120 G6
Four NICs
ETH0 for VoIP 
ETH1 for internet and firewall
(first two on-board)
ETH2 for link with local LAN
ETH3 bri card
(last two PCIe)

Symptoms: All NICs are running ok after boot. Few hours later, ETH1 claims link is down. Plug/unplug cable changes nothing. Rebooting server solves ETH1 link, until now.
Now, ETH1 is not recognized and ETH3 is recognized as ETH1. Restarting network services solves nothing.

Is this 100% hardware problem? Where to go to troubleshoot?

Comment: Have you checked for a driver update? I know on the ProLiant it has a Ethernet block for the 4 NICs. There might be a driver issue with your OS causing confusion between the NICs. Have you also tried a full clean uninstall of the drivers for the NICs and reinstall?